# Use a variable within a Powershell call to WSL

Tags: powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Is there a way to use a variable within a call to WSL from Powershell.

So I'm looking for a way that I can capture an environment from a user, then use that variable within the call to WSL:

```
...
if ($env -eq 'STAGING' -or $env -eq 'S')
{
    $ip = '10.24.65.177'
}
elseif ($env -eq 'UAT' -or $env -eq 'U')
{
    $ip = '10.24.98.25'
}

<other stuff>

wsl scp -i ~/.ssh/my_prv_key somefile.zip ec2-user@$ip:/home/ec2-user/
```

But the $ip isn't expanded as I expected it to be. I appreciate that I could just do the whole thing in an If/else or case, but that seems clunky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commenter [js2010](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6654942/js2010) noted, the colon after `$ip` is the actual problem. The colon is parsed by PowerShell as the scope separator (as in `$local:var`), so we have to make the substitution parser stop before the colon. This can be done by enclosing the variable name in curly braces.

```
wsl scp -i ~/.ssh/my_prv_key somefile.zip ec2-user@${ip}:/home/ec2-user/
```

Comment: The colon is probably the problem when it's not quoted.

Comment: @js2010 Thanks, good to know. You don't need to include the colon in the variable though. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the colon in the variable.  It has a special meaning in powershell commands.

```
$ip = '10.24.98.25:'
```

Comment: This is a valid solution, but I expect that future me would forget why the colon had been included in the variable, hence marking the curly brace solution as the accepted answer